# i cant apply grid-template-columns and grid Gap Css in Miscrsoft Edge (version - 20.10240.17146.0)

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I am using Miscrosoft Edge version 20.10240.17146.0
and I am have used

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin: 15px 15px;
}
```

this CSS and edge doesnt Support this CSS.
Is there any alternate way so I can see my site better in Edge

Comment: Newest Edge does support Grid: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: but i need solution for version i mention above @Michael_B

Comment: Post enough code so we can reproduce the layout.

Comment: You can see this examle its working fine in Chrom but test it in Edge its not working "grid-template-columns" is not working in Edge @Michael_B
https://codepen.io/MicrosoftEdgeDocumentation/pen/mMQqZX